# How can I group similar results from mySQL database in foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id = :id ');  
$pdo->execute(array('id' => $id));
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $name = $row["name"];
     echo $name."<br>";
}
```

The result of my loop is right now-

```
cat
cat
cat
cat
dog
bird
```

I want to group results if they are similar, so I get as a result like this-

```
cat
dog
bird
```

Comment: `$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name FROM animals WHERE id = :id '); `

Comment: If you only want the name, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM animals....` or you can use the group by function by adding `GROUP BY name` to the end of your query.

Comment: DISTINCT is your key word!

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the animals table to begin with?  is there an animal type table that lists the varies types that you should be selecting from instead?  while distinct/group by may work, I'd want to understand the data better before using either of them; and ensure the design doesn't have these classifications elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

different ways:-

1.[DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):-

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name FROM animals WHERE id = :id ');
```

2.[GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):-

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM animals WHERE id = :id  GROUP BY name');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)**

**Example**

```
 $pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id = :id  GROUP BY name');
```

OR you can use **[DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)**

**Example-**

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name FROM animals WHERE id = :id');
```

Answer (score 4):

Sql DISTINCT Clause is your Friend.
Alternatively, doing by php will go this way,

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals WHERE category = :category ');  
        $pdo->execute(array('category' => $category));
        while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $name[$row["name"]] = $row["name"];
            echo $name."<br>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DISTINCT` of mysql to get the unique records from your table as

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT name FROM animals WHERE id = :id ');
```